# How can I get a File object from a file located /res folder in android?

Tags: android

I need to pass a text File object (such as `File file= new File(mURLPar.path.value)` ) to a fucntion which only accept File object par.

It seems that only two folders in /res folder (/assets and /raw) where I can place the text file.

I place the text file in /raw folder, but  I only can get a InputStream using the following code.

I hope to get a File object, how can I do?  Thanks!

**Code**

```
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourfile);
```

Comment: You should place your file in assets folder and access it using AssetManager

Comment: You need to Write that file in storage or in cache then only you get file object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the file in cache folder or internal/External storage.
then only u get file object.

```
    File file=new File(getCacheDir()+ File.separator+"temp.txt");
file.createNewFile();
outputStream =new FileOutputStream(file);
int read = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
}
outputStream.close();
```